# Kafka: Can we have consumers subscribing to same topic but have different pipelines inside the topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 200 Kafka consumers who can do either of these things,
1. They can subscribe to 200 different topics, and will consume messages that are sensitive.
2. All 200 consumers can subscribe to a single topic.

Problem:
1. Is it a good design to create 200 or large number of topics?
2. In second scenario, how we will achieve the implementation where the messages published to the topic should be sent to a particular consumer only based on some parameter.

Comment: What we used to do is to have a single topic with a large number of partitions, the producers were forced to use some dedicated partition and consumers were consuming from these dedicated partitions. hence avoiding many topics, though there were some scaling challenges later on, but just giving a thought

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it a good design to create 200 or large number of topics?

Kafka uses replicated files for topics and since it uses offset based message transmission number of topics has no direct effect on performance so it is not a problem.

> 2. In second scenario, how we will achieve the implementation where the messages published to the topic should be sent to a particular
>      consumer only based on some parameter.

You can not do this based on a parameter, if you need a message to be delivered to exactly one consumer then you need to group all the consumers in a single consumer group and make the whole group listen to a topic. This way a message will be consumed by only one consumer in that consumer group.

If you need to sequential (ordered) message consumption then you need to create your Kafka topic with only 1 partition.

Comment: Hi @shazin, Thanks for clarity on 1. Now as far as 2. is concerned, my requirement is, if the producer is producing data for consumer1, then only consumer1 should be able to consume that, same goes for all other consumers. I want to target a individual consumer while producing, is it possible having one topic?

Comment: You are expecting some sort of a routing to a particular consumer based on a message element. This is not possible out of the box in Kafka. Kafka provides a dumb queue smart clients approach as opposed to ESBs smart queue dumb clients approach. If you want one consumer to consume all messages from a Kafka topic then you have to have only one consumer per topic.

Comment: can we achieve this using a custom partitioner ? and assigning a particular partition inside a topic to a particular consumer? is this approach worth giving a try?